# Why is the data not updated with useState when I do a map on another array of object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a website and I'm building it with React-Redux.
I have (API) which is a (Data Array of Object) and its length is (16 elements). And fetch the data through Axios and save it in the (reducer ) and fetch the data to the required component through (UseSelect), and the data comes to me correctly as I want.
Then I try, through (UseEffect), to extract the image link from the data and put it in a new (state), but when I do a map on it, it does not extract the data correctly.

What is my error and what is the solution?

API DATA

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"16.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","White"],
        "img":"images/product-01.jpg",
        "category":"women"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Herschel supply",
        "supplier":"Herschel supply",
        "price":"35.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-02.jpg",
        "category":"women"
         
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"Only Check Trouser",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"16.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","White"],
        "img":"images/product-03.jpg",
        "category":"men"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "name":"Classic Trench Coat",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"16.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-04.jpg",
        "category":"women"
    },
    {
        "id":5,
        "name":"Front Pocket Jumper",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"16.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-05.jpg",
        "category":"women"},   
     {
        "id":6,
        "name":"Herschel supply",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"16.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-06.jpg",
        "category":"accessories"
    },
    {
        "id":7,
        "name":"Femme T-Shirt In Stripe",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"76.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-07.jpg",
        "category":"women"
    },
    {
        "id":8,
        "name":"T-Shirt with Sleeve",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"16.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-08.jpg",
        "category":"women"
    },
    {
        "id":9,
        "name":"Pretty Little Thing",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"96.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-09.jpg",
        "category":"accessories"
    },
    {
        "id":10,
        "name":"Square Neck Back",
        "supplier":"Herschel supply",
        "price":"35.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-10.jpg",
        "category":"women"
         
    },
    {
        "id":11,
        "name":"Lightweight Jacket",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"16.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-11.jpg",
        "category":"men"
    },
    {
        "id":12,
        "name":"Lightweight Jacket",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"16.61 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-12.jpg",
        "category":"accessories"
    },
    {
        "id":13,
        "name":"Lightweight Jacket",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"16.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-13.jpg",
        "category":"women"},   
     {
        "id":14,
        "name":"Lightweight Jacket",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"16.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-14.jpg",
        "category":"women"
    },
    {
        "id":15,
        "name":"Lightweight Jacket",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"76.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-15.jpg",
        "category":"accessories"
    },
    {
        "id":16,
        "name":"Lightweight Jacket",
        "supplier":"Esprit Ruffle Shirt",
        "price":"16.64 $",
        "Size":["Size s","Sizes M","Size L","Size XL"],
        "color":["Red","Blue","Grey","White"],
        "img":"images/product-16.jpg",
        "category":"women"
    }
]
```

my code in component

```
export  function ShopDetails() {
 
const prodectData=useSelector((state)=>state.productData)
const [option,setOption]=useState("")

console.log(prodectData)///See the result in the picture below // ((Line 25))

    const [image,setImge] = useState([{
}]);


  useEffect(()=>{

      prodectData.map((el)=>(
        setImge([...image,{original:el.img,thumbnail:el.img}])
      
       )
    )

    console.log(image) /// See the result in the picture below  ((line 38))
  
},[prodectData])

    return (
    //Some Codes
 )
}
```

[image]

Comment: try setImage(prodectData.map((el)=>({original:el.img,thumbnail:el.img})))

Comment: It works. But why is my solution wrong?

Comment: you can use your solution as well like prodectData.map((el)=>(
        setImge((preState)=>[...preState,{original:el.img,thumbnail:el.img}])
       )
    )

Comment: setState is async operation. when you call setImage in the map loop each time, the data in image has not been updated yet. so you need to use a callback function as the setImage parameter. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Haha no problem! you solved new question already! Enjoy coding :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setImge is for updating image state. If you wanna use the image List as a state. You should do as below.

```
// example
const productData = useSelector(state => state.productData);
const imageList = productData.map((data => {original: data.img, thumnbnail: original.img})); // you make a img List you want!
const [image, setImage] = useState(imageList);

..... render logic
```

That's it! You don't need to use useEffect cuz whenever the productData in redux store changes, React re-render all components that use the productData. It means new productData you just fetched will be put image state in useState.

Comment: I want to extract the data to pass it to another component and I want it to be in the form of (array of object) and I do not want to modify the data

Comment: Jerry's solution and my solution works the same. I made the codes above for code quality. The reason your first code fails is you call setImage useState function whenever the map function iterates. So setImage(List.map(item => { object }) means you make imageList first and then put the List result into image state. If my answer helped you, please select my answer please :D

Comment: Thank you for this information. But do you know why my solution is not working? What is the explanation for this?

Comment: Yes I know and I explained above already. The reason your code failed is that you call setImage function in the map function. When your map function iterates, setImage function call again and again. You know useState shouldn't be used in map loop. So Jerry and my solution is that call setImage just once when the map function return the imageList as a result. The list will be put in the state cuz you call setImage next.

Comment: But what is the problem with the setstate calls more than once on the map? What is the name of this problem to search for it on Google

Comment: setImage runs asynchronous, not synchronous. If you wanna understand this issue more, search how useState work and how it affects on rendering. Also how map function works and what returns it and why you should type code like above. You will  find an answer.

Comment: Did u cancel selecting answer? I think I helped u. I spent lots of time on helping you last night. Please consider it again.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I read an article yesterday that caused me a misunderstanding, and I thought your answer was inaccurate.
But I realized you were right
You can look at the problem I'm facing now, I've explained it here. If you can help

, I repeat my apologies to you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70474217/why-is-a-component-re-rendering-done-when-changing-the-value-of-the-props-sent-t